# What is a bounty and how do you post one?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)
>   [Where is the FAQ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33331/where-is-the-faq)

What is a bounty and how do you post one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq - see just under "What if I don't get a good answer"

Answer (score 0):

Look at the stack overflow FAQ's

https://stackoverflow.com/faq

under the section "What if I don't get a good answer?"